# Add value from a series of inputs to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

I have a page which is designed to add talking points to a textarea via checkboxes for a call center. Everything needs to be stored and operated from this one page because this will not be stored on a server, but as a local site that can be customized for each representative. I have a series of checkboxes which when selected initiate a script that reviews the checkboxes and adds the value of each selected checkbox to the CADI variable. I have specifically chosen to use a textarea so that it can be edited in real time, as opposed to adding it within a paragraph block.

There are, however, two things that I cannot figure out.

1. How can I have each checkbox add itself to the CADI variable instead of running a loop that looks at the current boxes checked?

Example 1: I selected checkbox 2 and then manually edited the textarea. Then, I selected checkbox 3 and checkbox 1, and I need to have them added without repeating any checkboxes or deleting any notes I've already edited.

1. Is there a more efficient way to change the .value of the checkboxes without editing the html code of each one individually?

The code is included below as it currently stands.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<!-- Declare the CADI string variable so that it can hold all of our data -->
<script>
var CADI = "";
</script>

<!-- See which checkboxes are checked, and add those fields to CADI -->
<script>
function AddToCADI()
{
CADI = "";
var check = document.forms[0].check;
var txt = "";
var i;
for (i=0;i<check.length;i++)
  {
  if (check[i].checked)
    { 
    CADI = CADI  + " // " + check[i].value ;
    }
  }

document.getElementById("wrapup").innerHTML = (CADI);
}
</script>

<!-- Clear the CADI variable's string field and all checkboxes -->
<script>
function Clear()
{
CADI= " "
document.getElementById("wrapup").innerHTML = (CADI);
var check = document.forms[0].check;
for (i=0;i<check.length;i++)
{
check[i].checked=false;
}
}
</script>


<!-- Copy Text to Clipboard -->
<script>
function ClipBoard()
{
Copied = document.getElementById("wrapup").createTextRange()
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}
</script>

</head>


<body>

<table width="700">

<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="background-color:#1E90FF";>

<h1>Click a button to add the it to the Wrap Up!</h1>

<td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td style="width:300px;height:500px;border:1px solid black;">

<b></b>

<form action="">

<!-- Checkboxes to add  to the CADI variable -->

<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>


<br>





</td>

<td id="quick" style="width:400px;height:500px;border:1px solid black;">



<!-- Checkboxes to add  Items to the CADI variable -->
<b></b><br>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<br>

<!-- Checkboxes to add  Items to the CADI variable -->
<b></b><br>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<br>

<!-- Checkboxes to add  Form Items to the CADI variable -->
<b></b><br>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<br>

<!-- Checkboxes to add  Items to the CADI variable -->
<b></b><br>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<br>

<!-- Checkboxes to add Written Appeal Items to the CADI variable -->
<b></b><br>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<br>

<!-- Checkboxes to add  Items to the CADI variable -->
<b></b><br>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>

<br>
</td>
<td id="quick" style="width:300px;height:500px;border:1px solid black;">

<b>Miscellaneous</b><br>

<!-- Checkboxes to add Miscellaneous  to the CADI variable -->

<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="AddToCADI()" name="check" value=""><br>

<p> </p>

<!-- Button to copy text to clipboard -->
<button onclick="ClipBoard()">Copy</button>

<br>
<br>


<!-- Button to clear the CADI variable -->
<button onclick="Clear()">Clear All Notes</button>
<br>

</form>



</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="width:900px;text-align:center;">

<!-- Field in which wrapup items will appear -->
<textarea id=wrapup rows="50" cols="100">
This is where your CADI is going to show up.
</textarea>

<!-- Field that will hold the text so it can be copied to the clipboard -->
<textarea id="holdtext" style="display:none;">
</textarea>

</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I need to have them added" added what? what should be added when you check a checkbox? what should happen when you edit textarea? you're question is unclear.

Comment: I need to have the .value of each checkbox added to the variable when the corresponding box is checked. The text stored in the variable will appear in the textarea, and that is what should be editable. I had to remove the strings that I was storing because those are business specific. I hope that helps.